# How i can test callback in jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have class SomeClass with method `SomeClass.fetch()`

```
var repository = {
    get: function(obj) {
        //...
    }
};

var cache = false;

var SomeClass = {

    init: function() {
        //...
    },

    fetch: function () {
        var _this = this;

        repository.get({
            method: 'getRecentDialogsList',
            success: function (result) {
                if (!cache) {
                    _this.set(result);
                    _this.sort();
                    _this.trigger('fetch:success', _this);
                }

                _this.trigger('fetch:ajaxSuccess', _this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How i can test whether `SomeClass.fetch()` and check have been called `this.set()`, `this.sort`, `this.trigger` with parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use spyes:

```
describe("SomeClass Test", function() {
    it("calls the set() method when fetch is called", function() {
        spyOn(SomeClass, "set");
        SomeClass.fetch();
        expect(SomeClass.set).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

You can even totally replace the called method (for example, if it takes a long time to be completed) with something like this:

```
spyOn(SomeClass, "set").and.callFake(function myFakeSet() {
  console.log("I've been called");
});
```

Comment: I must mock repository.get(), who call success callback in repository.get()?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you: Are you asking if you must mock `repository.get`? Then the answer is no, as it will call that success function that on its turn will call `SomeClass.set`.